Bootstrap not loading
I has downloaded bootstrap and put it in angular.json and in head tag, but it load only in home page and when i refresh the page, but i need that it load when i go to product/:id route, angular.json:
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],

bootstrap in index.html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

component html that i need bootstrap:
<div class="product-page">
<div class="product-container">
    <h1 class="product-title">Características</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        @for (row of caracteristicas; track $index) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>{{row.name}}</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{row.description}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>

network when i enter in the route:


network when i refresh the route:


The data i receive, but the only problem is on the bootstrap

can you create a stackblitz link to view the project

https://github.com/Necobgs/arara-colors-backend
https://github.com/Necobgs/arara-colors
need only create a category, product, product image and product feature

To know how add boostrap icons. If you use npm i boostrap you change the angular. json to add the .css and NOT and the styles in the index.html

Instead of loading bootstrap via CDN try installing bootstrap, using this command npm install bootstrap then import Bootstrap in their main CSS (style.css) import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

It not work, i tried only add this and i try removing Bootstrap from CDN and in angular.json

you dont need to remove it from the angular.json. Try adding it back and following these steps https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started
